# Transaction unconfirmed after almost 2 day,please help

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I tried to send a bitcoin transfer monday afternoon and it is still unconfirmed. Paid the default fee and the transaction has said high priority since i sent it.Can anyone help me get this confirmed? Would greatly appreciate any help!

The transaction is:
https://blockchain.info/tx/907e8e446585be642bf85d89b15a55e306fe9868ed713c0cec84781761bcbd7a

Comment: Don't rely on blockchain.info notion of 'priority', it is horribly outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction's fee is pretty high and its size is small. It usually should get confirmed right in the next block.

The reason it's still unconfirmed is that there currently is a very big number of unconfirmed transactions. [Around 57'000.](https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions) Usually, it's somewhere around 1'000 to 3'000.

[This already happened a few months ago](https://news.bitcoin.com/bitcoin-transactions-stuck/). The mempool back then was 8 MB big. Right now, it's 35 to 43 MB big (depending on who you ask) and a block being mined (which statistically happens every 10 minutes) can only reduce it by about 1 MB.

Inconveniently for you, the size of the mempool has skyrocketed since you made the transaction due increased frequency of transactions.

[image]

[image]

([Source](http://bitcointicker.co/networkstats/))

If it continues like this, the blocksize limit will likely be increased so a block can decrease the mempool by more than 1 MB.

Your fee (0.5907 mBTC/kB) is above the current mempool average (0.2871 mBTC/kB) but there are a lot of transactions with higher fees than yours. Because of this, the miners will pick other transactions instead of yours.

The only thing you can do if you really need the transaction to go through fast is to send it again with a higher fee, this time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,how would i be able to send it again?

Comment: This is a [transaction replacement](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_replacement). Usually, wallets won't let you spend the same coins again (and you want to spend the same ones again so only one of the transactions can eventually get through!) which is why you have to re-import the wallet's data file into the wallet software. The details depend on the wallet you're using but it has been discussed for different wallets on this StackExchange site and all over the internet.

Comment: Would you recommend doing this or is it just easier to wait it out? And again thank you

Comment: You won't lose anything but the time you spend doing it and maybe (only if the second one will be the one to become confirmed) the difference in fee you choose. As long as the second transaction isn't confirmed, the first one is still valid and miners may chose either one. If a miner comes across the second one while already knowing about the first one, they may drop the first one in favor of the second one and then process it faster than they would've processed the first one because the second one has a higher fee. So, yes. If the transaction was important enough for me, I'd do it.

Comment: The transaction was returned but I lost £20 any idea why this could of happend?

Comment: What do you mean by "returned"? Do you mean the equivalent of £20 in BTC (around 34 mBTC)?

Comment: The pending transaction was cancelled but out of the £150 equivalent of Btc only around £130 was returned to my wallet balance

Comment: That can't be unless you made a mistake and spent those £20 on a way too high fee. If you create a transaction, you dictate exactly what will happen (which money goes wheres) should it get confirmed.

Comment: Resent the transaction last night but when I checked today it showed that it was double spent and sent this afternoon,could this be a problem?

Comment: https://blockchain.info/tx/907e8e446585be642bf85d89b15a55e306fe9868ed713c0cec84781761bcbd7a

Comment: The 2 transactions are `ab09bbb5e6b59077901b5c4f4dc24404004ab549062e3912f9c40b99dd3c6ec0` and `907e8e446585be642bf85d89b15a55e306fe9868ed713c0cec84781761bcbd7a`. Both use 3 inputs and share 2 of them. `13z9cr9MeJuLqBDkudNHD2nrQ3qf2nrEW1` is your target address. One of the transactions uses a change address, the other one doesn't. One of them sends  0.2494729 BTC to the target address, the other one  0.24889752 BTC. The difference is 0.57538 mBTC which is equal to £0.34. One of the transactions sends 0.01631248 BTC (£9.66) to a (probably) change address. This change address is yours.

Comment: What you wanted to do is a double spend. The only way to make a tx invalid is to have any of its inputs spent already by a different tx (which has to make it into the blockchain first (the other one won't be able to after the first one made it)). What blockchain.info tells you by this message is that it has detected that there are 2 transactions spending (in part) the same funds. This means that if you're the receiver of the transaction, you should be skeptical you'll get the money until the transaction which goes to your address is confirmed. It's the same target address, here, though.

Comment: I didn't try to double spend it I sent the transaction again and this is what came up,would this impact how long it will take to be confirmed?

Comment: The idea was make the transaction again but with a higher fee, decreasing the time it takes for it to become confirmed.